# Using SDWebImage for UITableViewCell with optional image URL

Tags: ios, swift, sdwebimage

I am trying to the SDWebImage to populate my uitableviewcell with the image from a link from an API, the problem is the string is optional as the index in the api struct may or may not have an image. Here is the code:

```
        let imageString = content[index].originalImageUrl

        cell.theImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString!), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```

The problem seems to be that if the originalImageURL is Nil then it crashes due to found nil as it makes me force unwrap the url. I want it to be the case that if the url is nil it uses the placeholder image instead. How can I do this?

Comment: Don't use force unwrap. Use `if let`/ `guard let`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use force unwrap. you can use `if let`

```
  if let imageString = content[index].originalImageUrl{
    cell.theImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
    }else{
    cell.theImageView.image = UIImage(named: "placeholder.png")
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The `sd_setImage` method uses the `placeholderImage` in case the image cannot be retrieved from the supplied `URL`, so even if `URL` is `nil`.

This means that you can simply supply an incorrect URL string to the `URL` initialiser and instead of resulting in a runtime error, SDWebImage will simply use the placeholder.

```
let imageString = content[index].originalImageUrl ?? ""

cell.theImageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string: imageString), placeholderImage: UIImage(named: "placeholder.png"))
```